Jhipsters jdl does not generate entities
The following jdl:
entity Customer {
  firstName String required,
  lastName String required,
  email String required,
  phone String,
  status CustomerStatus required,
  company String,
  jobTitle String
}

entity Lead {
  source String required,  // How did the lead come in (e.g., website, referral, cold call)
  potentialValue BigDecimal required,  // Potential revenue from the lead
  status LeadStatus required,  // Stage of the lead (New, Contacted, Converted)
  contactedDate LocalDate,  // Date when lead was contacted
  followUpDate LocalDate  // Date for next follow-up
}

entity Opportunity {
  title String required,  // Title of the opportunity (e.g., "New Business with [Client Name]")
  amount BigDecimal required,  // Expected value of the opportunity
  closeDate LocalDate required,  // Expected closure date
  status OpportunityStatus required,  // Current status of the opportunity (e.g., Open, Won, Lost)
  probability Double  // Probability of closing the opportunity
}

entity Activity {
  type String required,  // Type of activity (e.g., call, email, meeting)
  description String,  // Description of what happened
  date ZonedDateTime required,  // When the activity occurred
}

enum CustomerStatus {
  NEW,
  PROSPECT,
  CLIENT
}

enum LeadStatus {
  NEW,
  CONTACTED,
  CONVERTED
}

enum OpportunityStatus {
  OPEN,
  WON,
  LOST
}

enum UserRole {
  ADMIN,
  SALES,
  MANAGER
}

// Relationships between entities
relationship OneToMany {
  Customer{leads} to Lead,
  Customer{opportunities} to Opportunity,
  Customer{activities} to Activity
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Lead{customer} to Customer,
  Opportunity{customer} to Customer,
  Activity{user} to User with builtInEntity
}

dto * with mapstruct
service * with serviceImpl
paginate * with pagination

correctly generates the json files, but does not generate the actual java (entity) classes:
INFO! Generating jdls .\jdl\crm-domain-v0.jdl
WARNING! The paginate option is deprecated, please use pagination instead.
INFO! The dto option is set for Customer, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.
INFO! The dto option is set for Lead, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.    
INFO! The dto option is set for Opportunity, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.
INFO! The dto option is set for Activity, the 'serviceClass' value for the 'service' is gonna be set for this entity if no other value has been set.
INFO! Generating entities Customer Lead Opportunity Activity
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/

  Application files will be generated in folder: C:\Users\ppastor\Desktop\novendavo\papaluz
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

(node:16744) [DEP0180] DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated.
✔ applying multi-step templates
✔ prettier configuration files committed to disk
✔ loading translations
✔ updating package.json dependencies versions
✔ prettifying sonar-project.properties
✔ adding package-info.java files
✔ sorting pom.xml file
✔ translating angular application
    force .jhipster\Customer.json
    force .jhipster\Lead.json
    force .jhipster\Opportunity.json
    force .jhipster\Activity.json
    force .yo-rc.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\error.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\login.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\password.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\register.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\sessions.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\settings.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\configuration.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\logs.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\metrics.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\activate.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\global.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\home.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\reset.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\health.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\cs\user-management.json
identical src\main\webapp\app\layouts\navbar\navbar.component.html
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\error.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\login.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\password.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\register.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\sessions.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\settings.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\configuration.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\logs.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\metrics.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\activate.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\global.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\home.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\reset.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\health.json
identical src\main\webapp\i18n\en\user-management.json
identical src\main\webapp\app\entities\entity.routes.ts
✔ files committed to disk

No change to package.json was detected. No package manager install will be executed.
     info No deployment configured
WARNING! The generated application could not be committed to Git, as a Git repository could not be initialized.
✔ Spring Boot application generated successfully.
  Run your Spring Boot application:
  ./mvnw (mvnw if using Windows Command Prompt)
✔ Angular application generated successfully.
  Start your Webpack development server with:
  npm start


Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
If you find JHipster useful consider sponsoring the project https://www.jhipster.tech/sponsors/

Thanks for using JHipster!

So why are the entities not generated? (also the array in .yo-rc.json, "entities: []" is also empty, but no error in the log)

I believe this should help you move forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76768991/9343066

@JoãoGonçalves how is that suppose to help?

try removing this row: "Activity{user} to User with builtInEntity" and generate again, if it works, you know what the solution is

@JoãoGonçalves it will again just create the jhipster json for each entity but will not create the entities themselves (java classes and angular components for it, which it should). Not a solution.
